# WGAN-GP loss explodes

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have been working on a project of Wasserstein GAN with gradient penalty. The project is with MRI/CT(3D data). When I was doing a **2D** implementation(slice by slice) everything **worked perfectly**. However, when I tried extending it to 3D the Generators loss explodes to really high values(~10^7).

1. I am using a patch size of (144,176,20)
2. Batch size of 4, 4 GPUs.
3. The architectures of Critic is borrowed from https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training
4. I am **NOT** using batch norm in Critic.
5. Doing 5 updates of Critic per one update of G.

I tried decreasing the number of filters in G, to make Critic and G more balanced. It still goes pretty high(10^5-10^6).